# Is value attribute of input tag a part of DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I have some default value, that should be passed to value attribute of input, so this will be controlled component. What I need to know, where I should initialize state, in `constructor` enter code here or `componentDidMount`? I find, that `componentDidMount` is the right place for initialization that requires DOM nodes. So that's why I ask about value attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said `componentDidMount` is the right place for initialization **but** exactly for the requirement that needs DOM node's measurements like **width** or **height** in browser after render (here you can use element's width for some purpose).

so in your case (i mean **input**), there is no need to set value in `componentDidMount`.

hence you can simply use **constructor** that's enough.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ref` to get value of `<input/>`, update `state` and initialize `this.inputRef.current.value`. This is working solution of question,

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.inputRef = React.createRef();
   this.state = {
     inputValue: 'This is App component'
   }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
   this.inputRef.current.value = this.state.inputValue;
  }
  keypressHandler = (event) => {
    if(event.key === 'Enter')
     this.setState({inputValue: this.inputRef.current.value});      
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <label>Type text and press enter</label><br/>
       <input type='text' ref={this.inputRef} onKeyPress={(event) => this.keypressHandler(event)}/>       
       <p>{this.state.inputValue}</p>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root' />
```